# Expected ';' at end of declaration in qt

Tags: c++

I want to put text edit string(id) in list(id2) on qt5.
But I got notified:"expected ';' at end of declaration"
What should I do?

```cpp
QString id= ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
QString id2.push_back(id);
```

Comment: `QString id2.push_back(id);` You can't declare something and call a method on it at the same time. You have to do `QString id2;` and then `id2.push_back(id);`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second line? What are you trying to do there? Do you want to define a new variable and initialize it to the same value as the first? Then do `QString id2 = id;`

Comment: Or better `QString id2(id);`

Answer (score 0):

this is the reason:

```
QString id2.push_back(id);
```

qt asummes you are using the class `QString` because you  are declaring a new variable/object.. and that is a syntax error....

just do:

```
QString id2;
id2.push_back(ui->textEdit->toPlainText());
```